# Multiple Edges Between Two Nodes in a Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want a graph in which nodes have more than one edge, and the number of degrees calculate these edges.
Can I implementation this with networks?
for example :

```
import networkx as nx 
g=nx.Graph()
g.add_edge("A","B")
g.add_edge("A","B")
```

result:

> ```
> nx.degree(g)
> ```

```
'A': 2,
'B': 2
```

Comment: See [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html) for an undirected graph or [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html) for a directed graph. Note that for plotting, the standard nx.draw only draws straight edges, what can be confusing for multigraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following solution...

```
import networkx as nx
g=nx.MultiGraph()
g.add_edge("A","B")
g.add_edge("A","B")
nx.degree(g)
```

> result:

```
MultiDegreeView({'A': 2, 'B': 2})
```

Hope to help you too...